# Get specific clicked items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the values stored in the 'class' attributes of the 'span' elements.  Example markup:

```
<dl>
<dt id="1"><a href="#"><span class="name">Fred Flintstone</span><span class="address">12     Main St</span></a></dt><dd>misc text</dd>
<dt id="2"><a href="#"><span class="name">Barney Rubble</span><span class="address">99 Bedrock Ln</span></a></dt><dd>misc text</dd>
<dt id="3"><a href="#"><span class="name">Harry Potter</span><span class="address">33 Dreary Ave</span></a></dt><dd>misc text</dd>
</dl>
```

Example jquery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var name = $('.name').html();
    var address = $('.address').html();
}
```

This returns just the span values from the FIRST dt element.

Would appreciate suggestions to help me solve the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use this :

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var name = $('.name', this).html();
    var address = $('.address', this).html();
}
```

The second optional argument you can pass to the jQuery constructor is the context in which the search takes place.

Comment: Just a note, a more efficient version of `$('.name', this)` would be `$(this).find('.name')` because the first actually calls the second after it's parsed.

Comment: @Samsquanch The difference is in the order of 10%. 10% of something which is already much faster than needed. So it's **not** worth taking in consideration compared to readability.

Comment: I agree, I was only mentioning a more efficient alternative. I generally use `$('.selector', this)` over the alternative, but I don't think most people know that all this does is call `.find()`.

Comment: Thanks, dystroy.  Have not seen this format before for using 'this'.  had tried every other permutation.  Much appreciated.